# Ionic/cordova Cannot read property 'styleDefault' of undefined

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, ionic-framework, ripple

I've followed [this](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/#get-your-app-running-on-windows-10) guide and I can't get it to work when running the ripple emulator in Visual Studio. This error shows up:
[image]

I havn't changed a thing, just followed the guide.

EDIT:
My app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)

            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Please post your app.js

Comment: Added. I didnt change any in it.

Comment: Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: I'm just launching the ripple web browser emulator, same problem with both iPhone and Android.

Comment: Which cordova version?

Comment: The Cordova CLI is 5.3.3

Answer (score 1):

According to the [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#statusbarstyledefault) documentation, this function is not supported on `android`.

Either comment out or delete the code:

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
```

Or try to put it in a try/catch block, if you want to keep the code for other platforms

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
  try {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log( "Statusbar.styleDefault() is not supported: ", ex );
  }
}
```

And even if you have not installed the plugin yet, add it to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Comment: Installed the plugin and added try-catch and it still happens. EDIT: 
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); also causes error, but I added a nullcheck. I seems like something with the projet setup is wrong since both causes errors.

Comment: I had to wrap my `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true)` code in a try/catch block as well in my project to solve issues on `android`.

Comment: Either you tap **success** each time or stop ripple and use `android emulator`

Answer (score 0):

People with similiary issue found a solution [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/18). It just removes the annoying box in the ripple.js emulator.

```
    // I define this as a global function since I use it in other places
function isRunningInRipple(){
   // in an actual device(or emulator) all url's in the webview are 'file:// ... ' (since I don't load any external urls)
   return document.URL.indexOf('http://') >= 0 || document.URL.indexOf('https://') >= 0;
}

var app =  angular.module('myApp', [ ' ...dependencies...' ]);
app.run(['$ionicPlatform', '$timeout', '...other services...', function($ionicPlatform, $timeout, ...other services...){

  function disableRipplePopup() {
    var dialogBody = parent.document.getElementById("exec-dialog");
    var overlay = parent.document.querySelector(".ui-widget-overlay");
    var ngDialog = angular.element(dialogBody.parentElement);
    var ngOverlay = angular.element(overlay);
    var hideRules = { "height": "0px", "width": "0px", "display": "none" };
    ngDialog.css(hideRules); // hide annoying popup
    ngOverlay.css(hideRules); // hide annoying popup's backdrop
  }

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    // ... some app bootstrap code    

    if(isRunningInRipple()) $timeout(disableRipplePopup);

   // ...  more app bootstrap code
  });

}]);
```